# cron job not running on aws + ubuntu + node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron

I am using this cron job package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

It works fine on my laptop (executes events at certain times properly). However, the cron jobs won't run on my AWS Ubuntu server. Does anyone know if there's additional configuration I need to make it work on AWS Ubuntu? Here's my code:

```
    var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;

    //Server
    app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT, function() {

    var job = new CronJob('0 35 0 * * *', function() {

        console.log('job runningggg');
      }, function () {
        console.log('job done!');
      },
      true 
    );


    job.start();
```

Comment: @brandonscript the logs don't print out anything on the AWS server. but they do print on my local dev server

Comment: yes - the app does run. sorry, but what do you mean if i can run `cron` from ssh directly?

Comment: i can and do ssh into the ubuntu server (that's how i turn on the app).. but i'm not sure how to run cron from the shell..

Comment: Hrmmm ok actually never mind - I mistakenly assumed that it leveraged the system's crontab to run a job (see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job)) but that's not the case - it's completely native Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check the server timezone. It probably run but just at different timezone as yours.

Better use this example to check if it's working properly. The example prints every second which make timezone different doesn't matter.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```